# "Cannot access private field" despite @:access, but only outside FlxState subclass?

Tags: metadata, haxe, private-members, haxeflixel

Running Haxe 3.2.1.

I was building something special that needed access to HaxeFlixel's internals, so I added this above the function that needed it:

```
@:access(flixel.FlxG.keys)
```

This worked, in the context of `override update()` in a `FlxState` subclass.

Then I wanted to move this code to a higher level[1].  So I made a new class (not a subclass of anything), put the code in a function in the new class instead, and **moved the `@:access` to above the new function.**

The new class won't compile, saying `Cannot access private field playback`.  Why is this, when I have the same `@:access` metadata I had working before?

[1] I.e. to be called via `FlxG.signals.preUpdate` so that it would also run if my `FlxState` subclass opened a substate, which normally pauses the parent state's `update()` (which I still want it to do.)

Answer (score 2):

For the "I'm not sure how it was working before" department:

Don't use the member directly in `@:access`(), instead use the class' type.  In this case, `FlxG.keys` is a `FlxKeyboard`, so the following works:

```
@:access(flixel.input.keyboard.FlxKeyboard)
```

Comment: You can use the member as well, but it needs to match the one you're trying to call.

Comment: I had tried that (I was calling keys.playback)--I had tried both `keys` and `keys.playback`.